# PHP not Inserting into MySQL database all statements are there

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if anyone had input as to why this statement isn't inserting into my MySQL database.  It's not showing any errors and when I enter the SQL statement in manually it inserts the info.

```
<?php

$host="mysql16.000webhost.com";
$user_name="a1611480_akaash";
$pwd="*****";
$database_name="a1611480_akaash";
$db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd);

$sql = "INSERT INTO mydata VALUES ('dude1', 'dude2', 'dude3', 'dude4', 'dude5')";

mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

Comment: are you sure you dont need `update` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the fact that mysql does not know which database to use for this SQL statement. 
Include `mysql_select_db`.

```
mysql_select_db($database_name);
```

To get any type of error in php (except fatals) enclose your code with a try block

```
try{
    // db code
}catch(Exception $e){
    // something is wrong
    echo "Oh God! I got this ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  It does seem strange to me though that even though I tell it the database to which I'm connecting it doesn't know to look at that database.

Answer (score 2):

To see the error do this:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error:".mysql_error());
```

And from your query i am assuming that you have one column and you want to add multiple values
So this maybe the format:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mydata VALUES 
        ('dude1'), ('dude2'), ('dude3'), ('dude4'), ('dude5);";
```

Comment: Agreed.  And stop using the MySQL functions and start using PDO or MySQLi.  That big red box on the documentation page is there with good reason ;)

Comment: **die** ing in the middle of code is not a good thing. There might be opened resources you need to close.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the error message part of this. It'll come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't mention the column names - see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
Also you forgot to select the database - mysql_select_db("my_db");

So your query would have to be something like "INSERT INTO mydata (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) VALUES ('dude1', 'dude2', 'dude3', 'dude4', 'dude5')";

Edit: Of course Corey is right. It's just a better practice I think - I always do it :)

Comment: If all values are present, you don't have to list the columns.

Comment: From your own link: The first form doesn't specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to a remote host, are you sure you have the rights to do so?  Where is this code executed?

Outputting the result of `mysql_error()` would be useful!